# Как спарсить данные из json в таблицу на Python?

Tags: python, json

Прошу подсказать, каким образом можно перевести данные json в таблицу на Python?
Выгрузка вида:

```
{'data': [{'event_datetime': '2023-01-08 16:32:12', 'event_name': 'ВКЛ'},
          {'event_datetime': '2023-01-08 15:46:20', 'event_name': 'ВКЛ'},
          {'event_datetime': '2023-01-08 22:11:27', 'event_name': 'ВКЛ'},
          {'event_datetime': '2023-01-08 14:01:57', 'event_name': 'ВКЛ'},  
...
```

Нужно представление, где есть два столбца с данными event_datetime и event_name.

Comment: Я бы попробовал в `Pandas` скормить

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'data': [{'event_datetime': '2023-01-08 16:32:12', 'event_name': 'ВКЛ'},
                 {'event_datetime': '2023-01-08 15:46:20', 'event_name': 'ВКЛ'},
                 {'event_datetime': '2023-01-08 22:11:27', 'event_name': 'ВКЛ'},
                 {'event_datetime': '2023-01-08 14:01:57', 'event_name': 'ВКЛ'},
                ]
       }

df = pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
df
```

В `df`:

```
event_datetime  event_name
0   2023-01-08 16:32:12 ВКЛ
1   2023-01-08 15:46:20 ВКЛ
2   2023-01-08 22:11:27 ВКЛ
3   2023-01-08 14:01:57 ВКЛ
```